# Speed up fsockopen for server monitoring

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm working on server monitoring service and will need to monitor about 10.000 hosts every 5 minutes. I tried to use **fsockopen** to connect to port 80 and test server. It works OK unfortunately it's slow as it opens blocking connection by default.

I know there is a **stream_set_blocking** function available, but how to use it ?

Also I really wonder if it's a good way to go with fsockopen when it comes to server monitoring service.

Comment: The script you're trying to write already exists (except better). It's called Nagios: http://www.nagios.org/